Pydentic схема в качестве DTO (FastAPI)
Хорошо ли (best practice) pydantic-схему использовать в качестве DTO в FastAPI (ответ от SQLAlchemy в репозитории преобразовывать в pydantic-схему и возвращать в сервисный слой и т.д. или лучше прокидывать ответ алхимии наверх и в роутере преобразовывать в pydantic-схему перед отправкой клиенту)?
